# using variable after the subscribe block angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I m trying to use variable  after the subscribe block,but I can't
look at snippet:

```js
async check(){
   
  this.VersionNumber = await this.appVersion.getVersionNumber()
  
    this.settingsService.getjson().subscribe(item=>{
     this.djson = item
    alert(this.djson)  /// here work
 
  });
   alert(this.djson)  /// here not work, I got : [object:Object]
   
   
    if((this.VersionNumber !== this.djson)  ){
    this.presentAlertConfirm();
 
  }
    
  
  }
```

settings.service.ts

```js
getjson(){
     return this.http.get('./assets/jsonfile.json').pipe(map(res=> res['currentVers']))
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions are asynchronous that is why you get that error, you could create a function to have to logic to validate the data and call this function inside of the subscribe to have the value set when you want to use it.

Comment: yes you right your approach very logical I will try it, but I Have a question if we subscribe data in service, how can I call inside pages like example up @Jonathan

Comment: Could you add more information, like the scenarios or when do you want to request the service? I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean i want to subscribe the data inside service and call in home page,in my exemple I'm subscribe the data  in home page,I'm usually use .then() but in this exemple it's impossible  @Jonathan Lopez

Comment: You could transform your observable into a Promise with a pipe, but I remmend you to use observables in Angular. But I don't really understand why you want to this inside your service, I mean also you have to use the information in your component and you have to call your service independent it's a promise or observable

Comment: alright, thanks for your time @Jonathan Lopez